# Replace everything outside of Brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like a notepad++ regex to replace

> dep_rwy       :[FOR DEPARTURE EXPECT][RUNWAY]%deprwy%

into

> FOR DEPARTURE EXPECT
>   
> RUNWAY

There may also be three or for Brackets in each line that this would need to work on.

> wind_grp :variable:[VARIABLE BETWEEN]%vmin%[AND]%vmax%[DEGREES]

Should become

> VARIABLE BETWEEN 
>  AND 
>  DEGREES

What i have so far is

```
(.*)[(.*)](.*)
```

Comment: Please give an explample for the expected output in the three and four "brackets per line" case, e.g. should the third and fourth be skippped or somehow used.

Comment: You should also show us what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: wind_grp :variable:[VARIABLE BETWEEN]%vmin%[AND]%vmax%[DEGREES] should become VARIABLE BETWEEN new line AND new line DEGREES

what i have so far is (.*)\[(.*)\](.*) replaced by \2 but it will only take one of the Brackets

Comment: @Dreagan I added your comment information to your question. Check if it's ok.

Comment: Thanks i did one more edit to it to make it just right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `[^\[\]]*\[([^\]]+)\]`
- **Replace With:** `\1\n`
- Check **regular expression**
- Click Replace or Replace All

**Explanation**

- one problem is that brackets are RE metacharacters, that means we have to escape each bracket, when we need a literal bracket, i.e. a literal bracket becomes `\[` or `\]` in the RE
- here in the RE we look for an optional part that may consist of everything **not** brackets (`[\[\]]*`)
- followed by an opening bracket, followed by somthing not a closing bracket (`([^\]]+)`) which is also captured into `\1` due to the parentheses, for reuse in the substitution
- whatever is matched above is completely replaced by whatever was captured into `\1` followed by a newline (`\n`), when you need windows-style lineendings, you might want to use `\r\n` instead

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I can't however upvote your answer as i don't yet have enough reputation.